# Test In App Purchases Android Developer Account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have recently set up basic In App Purchases in my Android app that I am building. The problem I am having is that every time I install the app, via USB, I get the error "This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help centre for more information.".

It seems that the only way I can do a real test, using real SKUs is by uploading to the beta test group and installing from there. This can take up to 2 hours.

I am aware that I can use the SKU "android.test.purchased" instead of my own SKUs which I have created with the Android dev console. This is not ideal as it slows down my development time.

I am sure I am missing something and I was hoping someone could please point me in the right direction.

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Karen.

Worked out my issue was due to not signing my app with the keystore each and every time I build the application and installed via USB.

This option can be found in File -> Project Structure
Then select the module that you are signing, and then the tab "Signing" from the top of the window.

From there you just need to press the plus and fill in your details for the keystore.

After which, you need to go to the "Flavors" and "Build Types" tabs and select the signing config (one you just created).